# See post parameters for POST request in a html tag input

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, beautifulsoup, request

How could I see the post parameters from [this website](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=resumo&tipoConteudo=7PhJ%20gAVw2g=)? I want to send a POST request filling that field (image below) but I couldn't find how to do it.

[image]

I've already inspected the Network section and searched for all possibilities, but no success.

Ps: Since this will be placed on a cloud environment, I won't have access to any web browser driver. For this reason, I can't use `selenium`.

Comment: “*Since this will be placed on a cloud environment, I won't have access to any web browser driver.*” How exactly did you reach the conclusion that these two things are mutually exclusive of one another…?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the `inspect` tap in Firefox or `inspect element` in Chrome before send the request and go to `network` tab then click to a button to send the request. You will see the request appear in this tab ( maybe you need to check on persist logs before doing the request). Then click on the post request and it will a page appear. In this page go to the request body section and you will see what you want.
[screenshot from the website with inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ5UN.png)